# How to fix:Can not find the tag library descriptor for “http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core”

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am getting error as below image,

[image]

I am first time gonna use JSTL from scriptlet.So let me tell where i am wrong?

Note:Even i tried `Go to Project Properties > Targeted Runtimes and select the server you are using (Tomcat 7.0 for me).` but no use.

How to fix this error?

Comment: Try adding JSTL JAR Files before proceeding to use JSTL Tags.

Comment: @PradyumnaSwain I tried but no use!.

Comment: You might have added in wrong directory!!! In your picture it's showing ZIP file just extract it and put the JAR file.

Comment: @PradyumnaSwain Ya you are right i didnt extract it.Now its working fine Thank you.!

Answer (score 0):

You might have added in wrong directory!!! In your picture it's showing ZIP file just extract it and put the JAR file